# How to unmarshel XML String to List using JAXB in Java

Tags: java, xml-parsing, jaxb

I am working on unmarshalling an XML into java object using JAXB. I don't know how to unmarshal a string in an XML element into List. This is what I have tried:

```
    private List<String> words;

    public List<String> getWords() {
        return words;
    }

    @XmlElement(name="Words")
    public void setWords(String words) {
        /* Converting String to List */
        this.words = Arrays.asList(words.split(", "));
    }
```

My XML:

```
<Words>A, B, C, D</Words>
```

Instead of List, the code gives me null. If I change the type of words from List to String, then it is working fine. Is it possible to convert from String to List or array?

XML parsing code:

```
File file = new File("path\\to\\xml");
JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(Myclass.class); 
Unmarshaller jaxbUnmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();
Myclass xmlContent = (Myclass) jaxbUnmarshaller.unmarshal(file);
System.out.println(xmlContent.getWords());
```

PS: The other question linked is different from this, here I am trying to get the String from XML element(a single element) and split and store it in a list. Whereas in the other, the question was splitting the XML string and storing some elements in list.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Parse XML string and build a list of strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37109094/parse-xml-string-and-build-a-list-of-strings)

Comment: There must be a problem different from the conversion by `split(", ")` and `Array.asList`. Does your xml parser work correctly? I just tried to split a `String listAsString = "A, B, C, D"` with your `Arrays.asList(words.split(", "))` and it worked.

Comment: @Abhinav - That is a different question.

Comment: @deHaar - That conversion works fine. But while parsing it is not giving correct result. I should have missed something while parsing. Is there any way to do this in JAXB?

Comment: Show us your parsing code, please...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I have figured out the problem and found the solution to get array of strings instead of list of strings.

```
private String[] words;

@XmlElement(name="Words")
public void setWords(String[] words) {
    /* Converting String to Array */
    this.words = words[0].split(", ");
}
```

The problem was method parameter type(`String`) and variable type(`List<String>`) were not same. It should be same in order to parse it correctly. I have changed both of them to `String[]` and put my logic in setter. Now the string in XML is parsed into `String[]`.